# How to code for date picker on the popup form in asp.net

Tags: javascript, ajax, calendar

I have created a popup form in asp.net using ajax modalpopupextender. Now I need to add date picker on the popup form. I tried using calendar extender but the calendar appears at the back (behind) the pop up form. Pls help me with this issue...

Comment: check the z-index of popup and  update the z-index of calendar more than popup .

Answer (score 1):

Based on your current scenario, it can be issue with css only. Check z-index of you calendar control over your popup control.

Comment: I have no issue with the z-index. Pls give me satisfied answer.